# React Native - how to declare a StyleSheet property in an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

[image]

I have a functional component in React Native which receives some properties, how can I declare StyleSheet type of property in TypeScript?

Comment: try `style: typeof StyleSheet`

Comment: @japrescott thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the type of a function/constructor by using `typeof`

```
    interface {
        style: typeof StyleSheet;
    }
```